# how to open multiple new tabs in qterminal with a bash script in debian 11 lxqt

Tags: shell-script, debian, gnome-terminal, top, lxqt

I am trying to create a bash script that will set up my all development stuff in an instant.

What I want the script to do: open 5 different tabs in one window.

1. clear terminal and start firefox-esr.
2. clear terminal and run top command.
3. clear terminal and start development server by using npm live-server.
4. edit a file by using vim.
5. for testing purpose only.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
qterminal --tab
#clear && top
```

When I try to open new tab using command I got this error:

`qterminal: unrecognized option '--tab'`

How can i open new tabs in terminal by using commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just end up  by installing gnome-terminal and remove qterminal.

Qterminal does not support this `--tab` option.

## Script current look

---

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --tab --hide-menubar --title="Firefox-esr" --working-directory ~/workshop -- firefox-esr
gnome-terminal --tab --hide-menubar --title="Server" --working-directory ~/workshop/methodTwo/reference/reactMainConcepts/ -- live-server --open=./index.html
gnome-terminal --tab --hide-menubar --title="Current Js" --working-directory ~/workshop/methodTwo/reference/reactMainConcepts/ -- vim
gnome-terminal --tab --hide-menubar --title="Side Js" --working-directory ~/workshop/methodTwo/reference/reactMainConcepts/ -- vim 
clear && top
```

And i added this in `~/.bashrc`

```
# function to set terminal title
function setTitle() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
  #askUser
}
setTitle Testing

function askUser(){
  ~/workshop/devSetup.sh
}
```

setTitle function is not my own created function.

I copied it from this ask ubuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1375280).

---

Now i can use my development setup by using this command `askUser`.

If something is wrong in this answer please tell me it will fix it as soon as possible.

Thank you!